# C Program not opening Serial on Arduino Mega

Tags: c, arduino, serial-port

I have a C program (win32 api) which communicates to my Arduino Mega via serial (USB).

I can communicate to the Arduino fine via the IDE's serial monitor.

If I plug in my Arduino and run the C program, the port does not seem to be opened properly and there is no communication.
In this case, if I open the serial monitor from Arduino's IDE (or another serial program) and then close it again, the C program then works perfectly.

Here is my port code from the C program (in this example it is passed 5 as this is the port the Arduino is using):

**CSerialPort.h:**

```
#pragma once

#include <Windows.h>

#define CP_BAUD_RATE_1200 CBR_1200
#define CP_BAUD_RATE_9600 CBR_9600
#define CP_BAUD_RATE_1155 CBR_1155
#define CP_BAUD_RATE_4800 CBR_4800
#define CP_BAUD_RATE_19200 CBR_19200

#define CP_DATA_BITS_5 5
#define CP_DATA_BITS_6 6
#define CP_DATA_BITS_7 7
#define CP_DATA_BITS_8 8

#define CP_STOP_BITS_ONE ONESTOPBIT
#define CP_STOP_BITS_TWO TWOSTOPBITS
#define CP_STOP_BITS_ONE_AND_HALF ONE5STOPBITS

#define CP_PARITY_NOPARITY NOPARITY
#define CP_PARITY_ODD ODDPARITY
#define CP_PARITY_EVEN EVENPARITY
#define CP_PARITY_MARK MARKPARITY
#define CP_PARITY_SPACE SPACEPARITY

typedef HANDLE PORT;

PORT OpenPort(int idx);

void ClosePort(PORT com_port);

int SetPortBaudRate(PORT com_port, int rate);

int SetPortDataBits(PORT com_port, int databits);

int SetPortStopBits(PORT com_port, int stopbits);

int SetPortParity(PORT com_port, int parity);

int GetPortBaudRate(PORT com_port);

int GetPortDataBits(PORT com_port);

int GetPortStopBits(PORT com_port);

int GetPortParity(PORT com_port);

int SendData(PORT com_port,const char * data);

int ReciveData(PORT com_port, char * databuffer,int bufferlen);
```

**CSerialPort.c**

```
#include "CSerialPort.h"
#include <time.h>

PORT OpenPort(int idx)
{
    HANDLE hComm;
    TCHAR comname[100];
    wsprintf(comname, TEXT("\\\\.\\COM%d"), idx);
    hComm = CreateFile(comname,            //port name
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, //Read/Write
        0,            // No Sharing
        NULL,         // No Security
        OPEN_EXISTING,// Open existing port only
        0,            // Non Overlapped I/O
        NULL);        // Null for Comm Devices

    if (hComm == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return NULL;
    COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts = { 0 };
    timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 50;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;

    if (SetCommTimeouts(hComm, &timeouts) == FALSE)
        return NULL;

    if (SetCommMask(hComm, EV_RXCHAR) == FALSE)
        return NULL;

    return hComm;
}
void ClosePort(PORT com_port)
{
    CloseHandle(com_port);
}

int SetPortBaudRate(PORT com_port, int rate)
{
    DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };
    BOOL Status;
    dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
    Status = GetCommState(com_port, &dcbSerialParams);
    if (Status == FALSE)
        printf("FALSE BAUD STATE");
        return FALSE;
    dcbSerialParams.BaudRate = rate;
    Status = SetCommState(com_port, &dcbSerialParams);
    return Status;
}

int SetPortDataBits(PORT com_port, int bits)
{
    DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };
    BOOL Status;
    dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
    Status = GetCommState(com_port, &dcbSerialParams);
    if (Status == FALSE)
        printf("FALSE DATABITS STATE");
        return FALSE;
    dcbSerialParams.ByteSize = bits;
    Status = SetCommState(com_port, &dcbSerialParams);
    return Status;
}

int SetPortStopBits(PORT com_port, int bits)
{
    DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };
    BOOL Status;
    dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
    Status = GetCommState(com_port, &dcbSerialParams);
    if (Status == FALSE)
        printf("FALSE STOP STATE");
        return FALSE;
    dcbSerialParams.StopBits = bits;
    Status = SetCommState(com_port, &dcbSerialParams);
    return Status;
}

int SetPortParity(PORT com_port, int parity)
{
    DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };
    BOOL Status;
    dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
    Status = GetCommState(com_port, &dcbSerialParams);
    if (Status == FALSE)
        printf("FALSE PARITY STATE");
        return FALSE;
    dcbSerialParams.Parity = parity;
    Status = SetCommState(com_port, &dcbSerialParams);
    return Status;
}

int GetPortBaudRate(PORT com_port)
{
    DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };
    BOOL Status;
    dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
    Status = GetCommState(com_port, &dcbSerialParams);
    if (Status == FALSE)
        return -1;
    return dcbSerialParams.BaudRate;
}
int GetPortDataBits(PORT com_port) {
    DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };
    BOOL Status;
    dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
    Status = GetCommState(com_port, &dcbSerialParams);
    if (Status == FALSE)
        return -1;
    return dcbSerialParams.ByteSize;
}
int GetPortStopBits(PORT com_port) {
    DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };
    BOOL Status;
    dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
    Status = GetCommState(com_port, &dcbSerialParams);
    if (Status == FALSE)
        return -1;
    return dcbSerialParams.StopBits;
}
int GetPortParity(PORT com_port) {
    DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };
    BOOL Status;
    dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
    Status = GetCommState(com_port, &dcbSerialParams);
    if (Status == FALSE)
        return -1;
    return dcbSerialParams.Parity;
}

int SendData(PORT com_port, const char * data)
{
    DWORD  dNoOFBytestoWrite = strlen(data);
    DWORD  dNoOfBytesWritten;
    BOOL Status = WriteFile(com_port,
                data,
                dNoOFBytestoWrite,
                &dNoOfBytesWritten,
                NULL);
    if (Status == FALSE)
        return -1;
    return dNoOfBytesWritten;
}

int ReciveData(PORT com_port, char * data, int len)
{
    DWORD dwEventMask;
    DWORD NoBytesRead;
    BOOL Status = WaitCommEvent(com_port, &dwEventMask, NULL);
    if (Status == FALSE) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    Status = ReadFile(com_port, data, len, &NoBytesRead, NULL);
    data[NoBytesRead] = 0;
    if (Status == FALSE) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

**Test Code:**

```
#include "CSerialPort.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool sendComms(char * msgSndPtr, int portNum)
{
    auto p1 = OpenPort(portNum);
    SetPortBaudRate(p1, CP_BAUD_RATE_9600);
    SetPortDataBits(p1, CP_DATA_BITS_8);
    SetPortStopBits(p1, CP_STOP_BITS_ONE);
    SetPortParity(p1, CP_PARITY_NOPARITY);
    SendData(p1, msgSndPtr);
    ClosePort(p1);
    printf("%s sent.\n", msgSndPtr); //debug
    //strcpy(msgSndPtr,"");
    return 1;
}


bool receiveComms(char * msgRecPtr, int portNum)
{
    bool status = 0;
    strcpy(msgRecPtr,"");
    SetPortBaudRate(portNum, CP_BAUD_RATE_9600);
    SetPortDataBits(portNum, CP_DATA_BITS_8);
    SetPortStopBits(portNum, CP_STOP_BITS_ONE);
    SetPortParity(portNum, CP_PARITY_NOPARITY);
    auto p1 = OpenPort(portNum);
    status = ReciveData(p1, msgRecPtr, 50);
    ClosePort(p1);

    if (!status) //if nothing is received, cancel out and show error
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s received.\n", msgRecPtr); //debug
        return 1;
    }
}

void main()
{
char msgRec[50];
char * msgRecPtr = msgRec;
char msgSnd[50];
char * msgSndPtr = msgSnd;

  while (!(strcmp("end",msgRecPtr)))
  {
    sendComms(msgSndPtr,  5);
    receiveComms(msgRecPtr,  5);
    printf("sent: %s\n, msgSndPtr);
    printf("received: %s\n, msgRecPtr);
  }
}
```

**The arduino code:**

```
int i = 0;

void setup() 
{
    // Initiate Serial
    Serial.begin(9600);
    while (!Serial) ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB
    Serial.println("serial ready");
}

void loop() 
{
   Serial.println("testing comms");
   i++
   delay (150);
   if (i == 10) {
      Serial.println("end");
   }
}
```

If anyone has had this problem using win32 or knows how the Serial Monitor opens it's port, that would be very helpful.

Edit: just to clarify, once the port has been opened once successfully (by any program apart from my C program), my C program then works fine and can open/close the port successfully until the next power cycle.

Thanks

Comment: Please show the code in you Win32 program where you set baudrate, bits, parity, stop bits and handshake. Those values should matches the settings in the Arduino.

Comment: @fpiette I set the baud, bits, stopbits and parity before I open the port. I set them to 8N1 which I believe is the default for the Arduino.
I've edited the question to show this.

Comment: I suggest you try using [PuTTY](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html) which is free and able to communicate thru serial port. You can easily play with serial com port settings. Then once you've got the correct parameters, concentrate on your own Win32 program. To debug it, you can use two USB/RS232 cables back to back (cross cable). One connected to your own program and one connected with PuTTY. When it works like that, replace PuTTY by Arduino.

Comment: I have used [DockLight](https://docklight.de/downloads/) a lot to develop my RS232 applications with PC and Arduino. Much like I suggested in the above comment using PuTTY.

Comment: Are you sure that it is the COM port number to give to `GetCommState()`, and not a handle?

Comment: @thebusybee yes, I have debugged with a printf statement and the code I have does work correctly for the GetCommState.

Comment: Well, it might have not returned an error, but the documentation says you need to pass a handle. Why don't you just set the parameters after `CreateFile()`?

Comment: @thebusybee Ok, I will try with a handle instead. Do you mean set the parameters inside the '''OpenPort''' function? Thanks for the hlep.

Comment: In many programs, the implementation for OpenComPort takes an argument as a string like this: "COM3:9600,8,N,1" for COM3, 9600 bauds, 8 bits, no parity and 1 stop bit. The `OpenComPort` parse the string and do the system calls required to setup the port. Additionally, it may contain information for handshaking (flow control) such RTS/CTS, DSR/DTR, XON/XOFF. Without it, it assume there is no handshaking (What you need for your Arduino actually). Why a string? Because most of the time this comes from a config file (INI, XML or other) or the user interface in the form of string.

Comment: @fpiette I tried your solution with PuTTY (I used CoolTerm as I use it a lot at work) - it connects fine with 9600 8 N 1 and communication is possible.
Based on the busybee's suggestion, I get an error setting the baud rate but the parity, bits and stopbits are fine.
If I remove the setting of baud, bits, parity, stopbits alltogether, but open the port with CoolTerm and then close it, my C program works fine. I guess the problem is I am not setting the baud rate correctly but I don't know why that is not working :S

Comment: Maybe CoolTerm also initialize **handshaking** (AKA flow control). You don't! Please read my previous comments. See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/ns-winbase-dcb) and pay attention to every item that contains *flow*.

Comment: @fpiette could you clarify, the Arduino DOES require handshaking or DOES NOT require handshaking?
I have read the documentation and understand the concept of flow control but I was not aware it was required for the Arduino (if it indeed is). Thanks for the help!

Comment: Arduino Nano do **not** use handshaking. See [Arduino Nano reference schematic](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/Arduino_Nano-Rev3.2-SCH.pdf). You must set PC side to ignore flow control. This is equivalent of using a 3 wire cable between two RS232 ports.

Comment: @fpiette Ok, the Nano does not, does the Mega use it? Thanks!
I also added more code to the OP to help.

Comment: I don't know for Arduino Mega. It doesn't use a standard serial to USB controller.

Comment: About your code: If you publish a complete program that I can just copy paste, I will look closer at it and even try it.

Comment: @fpiette the CSerialPort header and C file are there. My main program is about 8000 lines long but the test example replicates the problem. I think the issue is the baud not being set correctly.

Comment: It is only common sense to never try to "invent" two sides of a comm protocol at once.  Test one at a time with a known-correct sender or receiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed your code!

The major errors were:

```
Incorrect use of COM port number where a handle was required
Closing the port after sending data and before receiving response which flush input buffer
Almost no error check which prohibed to know what was wrong
```

In the test code, the main loop was incorrect. No data was sent and breaking the loop when "end" was received was wrong.

I moved COM port parametrization once after opening the port (could be inside OpenPort as well).

The way you handle receive is related to the communication protocol you define. I have not touched that part. If it would be my software, I would design the protocol as a *line oriented protocol* that is each message sent and received would be in the form of lines terminated by a CRLF pair. Receiving can then be in a loop, cumulating all characters until the end of line is found.

Here after the fixed source code. There are still plenty of romm for enhancement.

Test code:

```
#include "CSerialPort.h"
#include <stdio.h>     
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool SetComParameters(PORT comPort, int rate, int dataBits, int stopBits, int parity)
{
    if (!SetPortBaudRate(comPort, CP_BAUD_RATE_9600)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to set baudrate\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if (!SetPortDataBits(comPort, CP_DATA_BITS_8)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to set data bits\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if (!SetPortStopBits(comPort, CP_STOP_BITS_ONE)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to set stop bits\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if (!SetPortParity(comPort, CP_PARITY_NOPARITY)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to set parity\n");
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

bool sendComms(char* msgSndPtr, PORT comPort)
{
    SendData(comPort, msgSndPtr);
    return 1;
}

bool receiveComms(char* msgRecPtr, PORT comPort)
{
    bool status = 0;
    strcpy(msgRecPtr, "");
    status = ReceiveData(comPort, msgRecPtr, 50);
    return status;
}

void main()
{
    char msgRec[50];
    char* msgRecPtr = msgRec;
    char msgSnd[50];
    char* msgSndPtr = msgSnd;
    int portNum = 1;
    PORT com_port = OpenPort(portNum);                            
    if (com_port == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open COM%d\n", portNum);
        return;
    }

    if (!SetComParameters(com_port, CP_BAUD_RATE_9600, CP_DATA_BITS_8, CP_STOP_BITS_ONE, CP_PARITY_NOPARITY)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting parameters\n");
        return;
    }

    do {   // FPiette use of do/while instead of while loop
        strcpy(msgSnd, "Hello\r\n");
        if (!sendComms(msgSndPtr, com_port)) {  
            fprintf(stderr, "sendComs failed\n");
            break;
        }
        printf("sent: %s\n", msgSndPtr);

        if (!receiveComms(msgRecPtr, com_port)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "receiveComms failed\n");
            break;
        }
        printf("received: %s\n", msgRecPtr);
    } while (strcmp("end", msgRecPtr));

    ClosePort(&com_port);

    printf("Done.\n");
}
```

CSerialPort.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "CSerialPort.h"
#include <time.h>

PORT OpenPort(int idx)
{
    HANDLE hComm;
    TCHAR comname[100];
    wsprintf(comname, TEXT("\\\\.\\COM%d"), idx);
    hComm = CreateFile(comname,            //port name
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, //Read/Write
        0,            // No Sharing
        NULL,         // No Security
        OPEN_EXISTING,// Open existing port only
        0,            // Non Overlapped I/O
        NULL);        // Null for Comm Devices

    if (hComm == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return NULL;
    COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts = { 0 };
    timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 50;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;

    if (SetCommTimeouts(hComm, &timeouts) == FALSE)
        return NULL;

    if (SetCommMask(hComm, EV_RXCHAR) == FALSE)
        return NULL;

    return hComm;
}

void ClosePort(PORT* com_port)
{
    if (com_port && *com_port) {
        CloseHandle(*com_port);
        *com_port = NULL;
    }
}

int SetPortBaudRate(PORT com_port, int rate)
{
    DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };
    BOOL Status;
    dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
    Status = GetCommState(com_port, &dcbSerialParams);
    if (Status == FALSE)
        return FALSE;
    dcbSerialParams.BaudRate = rate;
    Status = SetCommState(com_port, &dcbSerialParams);
    return Status;
}

int SetPortDataBits(PORT com_port, int bits)
{
    DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };
    BOOL Status;
    dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
    Status = GetCommState(com_port, &dcbSerialParams);
    if (Status == FALSE)
        return FALSE;
    dcbSerialParams.ByteSize = bits;
    Status = SetCommState(com_port, &dcbSerialParams);
    return Status;
}

int SetPortStopBits(PORT com_port, int bits)
{
    DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };
    BOOL Status;
    dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
    Status = GetCommState(com_port, &dcbSerialParams);
    if (Status == FALSE)
        return FALSE;
    dcbSerialParams.StopBits = bits;
    Status = SetCommState(com_port, &dcbSerialParams);
    return Status;
}

int SetPortParity(PORT com_port, int parity)
{
    DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };
    BOOL Status;
    dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
    Status = GetCommState(com_port, &dcbSerialParams);
    if (Status == FALSE)
       return FALSE;  
    dcbSerialParams.Parity = parity;
    Status = SetCommState(com_port, &dcbSerialParams);
    return Status;
}

int GetPortBaudRate(PORT com_port)
{
    DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };
    BOOL Status;
    dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
    Status = GetCommState(com_port, &dcbSerialParams);
    if (Status == FALSE)
        return -1;
    return dcbSerialParams.BaudRate;
}

int GetPortDataBits(PORT com_port) {
    DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };
    BOOL Status;
    dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
    Status = GetCommState(com_port, &dcbSerialParams);
    if (Status == FALSE)
        return -1;
    return dcbSerialParams.ByteSize;
}

int GetPortStopBits(PORT com_port) {
    DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };
    BOOL Status;
    dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
    Status = GetCommState(com_port, &dcbSerialParams);
    if (Status == FALSE)
        return -1;
    return dcbSerialParams.StopBits;
}

int GetPortParity(PORT com_port) {
    DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };
    BOOL Status;
    dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
    Status = GetCommState(com_port, &dcbSerialParams);
    if (Status == FALSE)
        return -1;
    return dcbSerialParams.Parity;
}

int SendData(PORT com_port, const char* data)
{
    DWORD  dNoOFBytestoWrite = strlen(data);
    DWORD  dNoOfBytesWritten;
    BOOL Status = WriteFile(com_port,
                            data,
                            dNoOFBytestoWrite,
                            &dNoOfBytesWritten,
                            NULL);
    if (Status == FALSE)
        return -1;
    return dNoOfBytesWritten;
}

int ReceiveData(PORT com_port, char* data, int len)
{
    DWORD dwEventMask = 0;
    DWORD NoBytesRead = 0;
    BOOL Status = WaitCommEvent(com_port, &dwEventMask, NULL);
    if (Status == FALSE)
        return FALSE;
    Status = ReadFile(com_port, data, len, &NoBytesRead, NULL);
    if (Status == FALSE)
        return FALSE;
    data[NoBytesRead] = 0;
    return TRUE;
}
```

CSerialPort.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>

#define CP_BAUD_RATE_1200 CBR_1200
#define CP_BAUD_RATE_9600 CBR_9600
#define CP_BAUD_RATE_1155 CBR_1155
#define CP_BAUD_RATE_4800 CBR_4800
#define CP_BAUD_RATE_19200 CBR_19200

#define CP_DATA_BITS_5 5
#define CP_DATA_BITS_6 6
#define CP_DATA_BITS_7 7
#define CP_DATA_BITS_8 8

#define CP_STOP_BITS_ONE ONESTOPBIT
#define CP_STOP_BITS_TWO TWOSTOPBITS
#define CP_STOP_BITS_ONE_AND_HALF ONE5STOPBITS

#define CP_PARITY_NOPARITY NOPARITY
#define CP_PARITY_ODD ODDPARITY
#define CP_PARITY_EVEN EVENPARITY
#define CP_PARITY_MARK MARKPARITY
#define CP_PARITY_SPACE SPACEPARITY

#define bool BOOL

typedef HANDLE PORT;

PORT OpenPort(int idx);
void ClosePort(PORT* com_port);
int SetPortBaudRate(PORT com_port, int rate);
int SetPortDataBits(PORT com_port, int databits);
int SetPortStopBits(PORT com_port, int stopbits);
int SetPortParity(PORT com_port, int parity);
int GetPortBaudRate(PORT com_port);
int GetPortDataBits(PORT com_port);
int GetPortStopBits(PORT com_port);
int GetPortParity(PORT com_port);
int SendData(PORT com_port, const char* data);
int ReceiveData(PORT com_port, char* databuffer, int bufferlen);
```